# Count of dplyr is not working properly inside a function

Tags: r, dplyr, count, tidyverse

I am trying to print aggregate tables and plots for different columns but when i pass a column name it is saying 'object is not found'.
Here is a simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "age" = c(1,2,3),
  "name" = c("a", "b", "c")
)
l <- c("age", "name")

#function to loop through columns
func <- function(df, parameter){
  return(
    df %>% 
      count(parameter)
  )
}
```

When I call the above `func` like this

```
func(df, "age")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `parameter` is not found.
```

What could be the reason? Is it not allowed to pass column name as a string? If not, then how should I proceed? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn column name strings into symbols and inject them inside a data-masked expression with `!!!`. For more details, see the [symbolise-and-inject pattern of metaprogramming in R](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-metaprogramming.html#symbolise-and-inject).

```r
func1 <- function(df, parameter){
  return(
    df %>% 
      count(!!!syms(parameter))
  )
}

func1(df, "age")
#   age n
# 1   1 1
# 2   2 1
# 3   3 1

func1(df, c("age", "name"))
#   age name n
# 1   1    a 1
# 2   2    b 1
# 3   3    c 1
```

Comment: @SatyaPamidi if my answer has worked for you, you could consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We may use `across`

```
func <- function(df, parameter){
  return(
    df %>% 
      count(across(all_of(parameter)))
  )
}
```

-testing

```
> func(df, 'age')
  age n
1   1 1
2   2 1
3   3 1
> func(df, c("age", "name"))
  age name n
1   1    a 1
2   2    b 1
3   3    c 1
```